# Quel est le radical de « microscope » ?

Tags: grammaire, étymologie, terminologie, préfixes, suffixes

Je lis [sur Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affixe) qu'un affixe précède ou suit un radical. Or, sur le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/microscope#.C3.89tymologie), on lit que **microscope** ne serait composé que d'un préfixe et d'un suffixe. Cela me semble contradictoire.

J'aurais spontanément considéré **micro** comme un préfixe, et **scope** comme le radical. Pouvez-vous m'éclairer ?

Comment: Il s'agit en effet du radical. Ce serait en effet une bonne idée de rendre le contenu du wiktionaire un peu plus précis.

Comment: L'[article](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-scope) sur _-scope_ au _TLFi_ est intéressant ; par exemple le premier élément n'est pas systématiquement basés sur le grec etc.

Answer (score 2):

Le même dilemme se pose avec téléphone, mais les notions d'affixe ne sont pas disjointes de celle de radical : micro- est un préfixe, -scope est un suffixe, mais les deux correspondent aussi à la définition d'un radical *(Partie essentielle du mot formé sur une racine, qui sert de base pour la construction d'autres mots, d'après l'[atilf](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/radical))*.

Comment: Cela me semble pourtant exclu d'après Wikipédia qu'un suffixe soit un radical. De plus, @Stéphane ne semble pas convaincu non plus. As-tu une autre source détaillant le problème ?